# Mixing braces and globing is bash

Tags: bash, glob, braces

I'd like to replace the following loop in one of my bash scripts:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $nb) do   
  grep -h 'my pattern' $mydir/$my_dir_prefix$i/$myfile_prefix* 
done
```

by something like:

```
grep -h 'my pattern' $mydir/$my_dir_prefix${1,$nb}/$myfile_prefix*
```

but it fails... Depending on where I try to put double quotes, I get different results but never the right one.

All answers I saw around similar topics didn't solve this problem.
Any idea?

Comment: Brace expansions can't contain variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** First solution will work only for numbers 1-9, adding better one

Looking at [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are
>   either integers or single characters.
>
> ...
>
> Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions

So variables are treated literally.

**Solution 1. (will work only for numbers 1-9)**

But you should be able to use `[]` glob for your purpose:

```
grep -h 'my pattern' $mydir/$my_dir_prefix[1-$nb]/$myfile_prefix*
```

Regarding double quotes, you can add them everywhere, but not around glob's:

```
grep -h 'my pattern' "$mydir/$my_dir_prefix"[1-$nb]"/$myfile_prefix"*
```

**Solution 2.**

You can enable bash [`extglob` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and use extended pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob
grep -h grep -h 'my pattern' "$mydir/$my_dir_prefix"@($(seq -s \| 1 $nb))"/$myfile_prefix"*
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for... I don't konw why I focused on braces instead of doing everything with glob's onlys

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the `grep` out of the loop:

```
grep -h 'my pattern' $(for i in $(seq 1 $nb); do find $mydir -wholename "$mydir/$my_dir_prefix$i/$myfile_prefix*"; done )
```

You'll run into issues with weirdly named files (eg containing newlines or other whitespace), but you had those same issues with the original solution.